# Puppeteer - change input field

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

**Problem**: On hotel website ([Hilton Website](https://www.hilton.com/en/search/?query=Seattle,%20Washington,%20US&arrivalDate=2023-09-01&departureDate=2023-09-02&flexibleDates=false&numRooms=1&numAdults=1&numChildren=0&room1ChildAges=&room1AdultAges=&sessionToken=2dba9427-50ed-4bd5-8d01-54ee073fdb61)), I am having trouble changing text input under `Maximum Price`.

Note: In order to get to the screenshot, you have to click `All Filters` button.

[image]

I tried the follow and there was no error. However, the `Maximum Price` text does not change.

**Note:** I am using Node JS I think some of the solutions provided are TypeScript?

**URL Link to my screen recording of issue:** https://easyupload.io/ljh4gi

Entire Code

```
console.time('program'); // * Start the timer

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const constants = require('./hilton_constants.js');
const fs = require('fs/promises');

// * Main Function
let browser;
async function hiltonScan() {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    // * select `false` if you want to run non-headless mode for testing
    headless: false
  });
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1065, height: 15000 });

  // Block resources
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', (request) => {
      if (request.resourceType() === 'image' || request.resourceType() === 'font' || request.resourceType() === 'media') {
        request.abort();
      } else {
        request.continue()
      }
  });

  await page.goto('https://www.hilton.com/en/', { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });

  // Fill in Where to
  await page.type('[class="form-input w-full"]', "Seattle, WA, USA");

  // Click calendar UI 
  await page.click('[data-testid="search-dates-button"]');
  await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid="calendar-container"]');

  await fill_stayDates(page, constants);

  // Fill in # Room, # Guest
  await page.click('[data-osc-product="search-rooms-button"]');
  await page.waitForSelector('[data-osc-product="search-rooms-button"]');

  //* Number of Rooms and Adults logic for Hilton
  if (constants.NUM_ROOMS != 1 && constants.NUM_ADULTS != 1) {
    if (constants.NUM_ROOMS == 1) {
      // Add Adults
      const add_adults_icon = await page.$$('[data-testid="rooms-room-1"] [aria-label="Add adult to room 1"]');
      for (let i = 1; i < constants.NUM_ADULTS; i++) {
        // Press the "+" button in Rooms
        await add_adults_icon[0].click();
      }
      await page.click('[class="stroke-text"]');
    } else {
      // Add Rooms
      const add_rooms_icon = await page.$$('[data-testid="rooms-add-room"]');
      for (let i = 1; i < constants.NUM_ROOMS; i++) {
        await add_rooms_icon[0].click();
      }
      const add_adults_icon = await page.$$('[data-testid="rooms-room-1"] [aria-label="Add adult to room 1"]');
      const adult_diff_addn = constants.NUM_ADULTS - constants.NUM_ROOMS + 1

      for (let i = 1; i < adult_diff_addn; i++) {
        // Press the "+" button in Rooms
        await add_adults_icon[0].click();
      }
      await page.click('[class="stroke-text"]');
    }
  }

  // Click Find a Hotel button
  await page.click('[data-testid="search-submit-button"]');

  await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

  // Click Filter button
  await page.click('#filters-button-with-icon');

  // Click Show available hotels only
  await page.click('#showAvailHotels');

  await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

  // !THIS IS NOT WORKING: Change maximum price
  const inputSelector = 'input[id="maxPrice"]';

  await page.focus(inputSelector);
  await page.$eval(inputSelector, input => {
        input.value = '';
        input.click();
  });

  await page.keyboard.type('123', {delay: 200});

  //* HELPER FX: click to the correct starting month
  async function fill_stayDates(page, constants){
    const findMonth = async targetMonth => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        const month = await page.$eval('[id^="calendar-month-"]', el => el.textContent);
        if (month.includes(targetMonth)) break;

        const arrows = await page.$$('[data-testid="calendar-container"] > [class="flex justify-between"] button:not([disabled])');
        await arrows[arrows.length - 1].click();
      }
    };

      const chooseDay = async day => {
        const dayResult = await page.$$eval('button[id*=day-] span:not([class*=sr-only])', elements => elements.map(element => element.textContent));
        const dayIndex = dayResult.indexOf(`${day}`)
        await page.$$('button[id*=day-] span:not([class*=sr-only])').then(el => el[dayIndex].click());
      };

      await findMonth(constants.START_MONTH);
      await chooseDay(constants.START_DAY);
      await findMonth(constants.END_MONTH);
      await chooseDay(constants.END_DAY);

      // Close pop-up
      await page.click('[class="stroke-text"]');
    };
  }


// * Call the main function
(async () => {
  console.log('Starting the Hilton scraper program...');
  await hiltonScan()
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
    // Close browser regardless of what Promise returns only if browser is not null or undefined (`?` keyword)
    .finally(() => browser?.close());

    console.timeEnd('program'); // * End the timer and output the execution time
})();
```

Second Attempt (did not work either):

```
  // !THIS IS NOT WORKING: Change maximum price
  async function clearFocusedInput(page) {
    await page.keyboard.press('Home');
    await page.keyboard.down('Shift');
    await page.keyboard.press('End');
    await page.keyboard.up('Shift');
    await page.keyboard.press('Backspace');
  }
  // your test
  const inputSelector = 'input[id="maxPrice"]';
  
  await page.focus(inputSelector);
  await clearFocusedInput(page);
  await page.waitForSelector(inputSelector).then(input => input.type('222'));
```

Third Attempt (did not work either):

```
  // !THIS IS NOT WORKING: Change maximum price
  const inputSelector = 'input[id="maxPrice"]';

  await page.focus(inputSelector);
  await page.$eval(inputSelector, input => {
        input.value = '';
        input.click();
  });

  await page.keyboard.type('123', {delay: 200});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use native `type` from `ElementHandle` to achieve your goal and clear input by keyboard hotkeys before. That would emulate native user behavior.

```js
   // somewhere in utils
async function clearFocusedInput(page: Page) {
  await page.keyboard.press('Home');
  await page.keyboard.down('Shift');
  await page.keyboard.press('End');
  await page.keyboard.up('Shift');
  await page.keyboard.press('Backspace');
}
   // your test
   const inputSelector = 'input[id="maxPrice"]';
   
   await page.focus(inputSelector);
   await clearFocusedInput(page);
   await page.waitForSelector(inputSelector).then(input => input!.type('222'))
```

Also you can use open-source [library](https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai) that handle tricky async relations between sites and puppeteer.

```js
import { type } from 'bubanai-ng';

// your test file

    const inputSelector = 'input[id="maxPrice"]';
    await type('222', page, inputSelector);
```

[Reference](https://wix-incubator.github.io/bubanai/modules/src.html#type)

As a third option, you can try to click on cleared input and type with delay

```js
 await page.click('#showAvailHotels');

 // don't use waitForNavigation there

 const inputSelector = 'input[id="maxPrice"]';

 await page.focus(inputSelector);
 await page.$eval(inputSelector, input => {
      input.value = '';
      input.click();
 });

 await page.keyboard.type('123', {delay: 200});
```

Comment: I used below but it did not work:


```
  // !THIS IS NOT WORKING: Change maximum price
  async function clearFocusedInput(page) {
    await page.keyboard.press('Home');
    await page.keyboard.down('Shift');
    await page.keyboard.press('End');
    await page.keyboard.up('Shift');
    await page.keyboard.press('Backspace');
  }
  // your test
  const inputSelector = 'input[id="maxPrice"]';
  
  await page.focus(inputSelector);
  await clearFocusedInput(page);
  await page.waitForSelector(inputSelector).then(input => input.type('222'));
```

Comment: @NelsonMak Are you sure it doesn't work for you? Look video - https://monosnap.com/file/qhYCmaKvIWTS9mB77CpjOe2Vp5Sv36 - for me it works.

Comment: This code also works for me:

    const inputSelector = 'input[id="maxPrice"]';

    await page.focus(inputSelector);

    await page.$eval(inputSelector, input => {
      input.value = '';
      input.click();
    });

    await page.keyboard.type('123', {delay: 200});

Comment: Thanks Yaroslavm. I'm really not sure why it works on yours but not mine. This is my screenrecording: https://easyupload.io/ljh4gi

I've also uploaded my entire code

Comment: @NelsonMak I fixed your case) You don't have problems with typing in input. You have problems with `waitForNavigation` which is stuck. Don't use `waitForNetworkIdle` or `waitForNavigation` without purpose. It's additional place of flakiness. They can sometimes perform circular looping, also in your case you don't have navigation.

Comment: Thanks so much Yaroslavm your solution works! I thought about the waitForNetworkIdle causing issues but never actually tested it.